# Cannot apply foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to get a list of all area in my database:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var carreras = repo.FindAllCarreras().ToList();
    AreaRepository area = new AreaRepository();
    ViewData["Areas"] = area.FindAllAreas(); //Return IQueryable<>
    return View("Index", carreras);
}
```

And in the View:

```
<% foreach (var area in ViewData["Areas"])
       { %> 
           <p><%: area %></p>
    <% } %>
```

I get an error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because
>   'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I think the best route would be modifying the query in the `CarreraController` and creating a linq query that returns all the names and saving it to a simple `List<string>`.

How can I achieve this?

```
ViewData["Areas"] = area.FindAllAreas().Select(????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewData is a dictionary from string to object. So you are basically doing

```
object o = ViewData["Areas"];
foreach(var area in o)
...
```

Just use a cast:

```
foreach(var area in (WhateverYourCollectionTypeIs)ViewData["Areas"])
```

Answer (score 0):

cast ViewData["Areas"] to `(IEnumerable<AREATYPE>)ViewData["Areas"]`

Comment: I'm not sure what I should be casting to. Area is a DB table, and using Linq-to-SQL as ORM. What should the IEnumarable type be? :\

Comment: @Sergio the same type you get in your `IQueryable<>` from `FindAllAreas`.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia whatever is returned by `FindAllAreas()` method. Probably something like `Area`.

Comment: That method returns an IQueryable<Area>, but in the View intellisense doesn't 'consider' it and doesn't show its properties or anything.

Comment: apply ToList() on FindAllAreas()